# How does correlation work in an image?

Tags: image-processing, correlation

The discrete function for correlation over 2 dimensions is

$$ C(x,y) = \sum\limits_{p=1}^{x_{res}} \sum\limits_{q=1}^{y_{res}} f(p,q)h(p+x, q+y)$$

where x,y is a coordinate in the image, f is the image, and h is the template. $x_{res}$ and $y_{res}$ are the dimensions of the images.

I do not understand how this works, because of adding x and y to p and q respectively. This will translate the template out of the bounds of the image.

If $h(p+x, q+y)$ is replaced with $h(p-x, q-y)$, then the template with be translated to the coordinate x,y in the image. However I'm told this is convolution not correlation.

I tried to implement it in code to try and understand: https://jsfiddle.net/ua5d1uo2/ as you can see, using + just gives a matrix of zeros. but using - the highest number in the matrix is where you'd expect it to be (where the template is matched in the image).

Comment: This function makes more sense to me if the f  is the template, h is the image, x_res and y_res are the dimensions of the template, and x and y are the coordinate pixel on the image.

Comment: Yes it does to me as well, but I'm assured that is not the case.